# Python 3.x - Web Server - extract json body from POST request

Tags: json, python-3.x, http-post

I am sending a Post request with a json body to a server but can not extract the json file  when it arrives. I have does exhaustive searches but to no avail. I have provided both client and server scripts to illustrate what is happening.

All I need is to extract the json portion at the end of the received string so I can analyze the request and return the appropriate data.

I'm sure it's simple but I can't seem to find the answer. Any direction would be appreciated

## ***

## CLIENT:  script to test Server

import json
import requests

def info_send():

```
url = 'http:1234abcd.ngrok.io'

payload = {
    'command': '["command", "status", "off", None]',
    'userID': 'userID string',
    'status': 'current status',
}

requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

info_send()

## ***

## SERVER: receives json POST request

```
HOST, PORT = '', 5000

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)

print('Listening on port %s' % PORT)

while True:
client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
request = client_connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
print(request)
```

## ***

## This is what is printed at the server

POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 1234abcd.ngrok.io
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 112
X-Forwarded-For: 112.162.214.265

{"command": "[\"command\", \"status\", \"off\", None]", "userID": "userID string", "deviceID": "current status"}

Comment: I figurred it out using regular expressions:


    request = client_connection.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

    data = str(request).replace('\\"', "'")
    data = re.findall(r'{(.*?)}', str(data))
    data = data[0]
    data = (json.loads('{'+data+'}'))